# .net 7 xUnit Debugger Does Not Hit a Breakpoint in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, .net-core, breakpoints

Spec: Win 10, Visual Studio Pro 2022 v17.7.4; .Net SDK v7.0.4
I have a solution with a bunch of different projects in it and one of them is a net7.0 xUnit Test proj. (converted from netstandard 2.0)
When I set a breakpoint to debug a test, it behaves like its just running a test instead of debugging it.

1. Looks like the debugger gets launched, but the breakpoint doesn't get hit. Test produces a result (After building for debug -> .pdb file is in the bin -> Debug -> net7.0 dir so I assume all symbols loaded)
2. I tried creating NUnit .net7.0 test -> same behavior.
3. I tried creating xUnit .net48 test proj -> weirdly debugger works as expected.
4. I tried putting Debug.WriteLine("In Debug!"). Debug output does not print the message.
5. Updated xunit.runner.visualstudio to 2.5.1. Didn't help.
6. Ran git clean -xdf on the repo, deleted all VS temp files, repaired VS through Installer, and  reainstalled .net SDK (I wonder if, when I ran sdk installer, it might have detected that I already used the latest and hadn't actually reinstalled anything? but I doubt that's the problem) -> so all this didn't help.

---

I left these for the end as these are solutions from other Stack Overflow posts that people ran into
7. I checked if the Debug Profile was missing; it wasn't. I created a new profile to make sure. Didn't help.
8. First, disabled all debugging settings in VS Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General. Didn't help. Enabled all, didn't help.
9. Enabled/Disabled Hot Reload during debugging.
10. launchSettings.json is not in the projects.

Thoughts: At this point I think its either some cached data thats interfering, or a .net bug.

Throw your ideas at me. Thanks!

Comment: "so I assume all symbols loaded" if you run in Debug - check the Modules panel to see if the symbols are actually loaded. And if you can repo this on a smaller project (point 2) provide it with your question so we can test to see if this is reproducible.